# ssh problems during deploy with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I'm getting permissions errors while trying to deploy my rails app to a friend's server. I'm running rails 3.1.3, ruby-1.9.2-p290, capistrano 2.11.2, Mac OS 10.6.8, and we have ssh keys set up. However, we can't figure out where the permission issues are coming from. We think it might be that capistrano is trying to push the code from the git repo AS THE GIT USER to the deploy directory, or something like that. But this is our first deploy attempt, so we're not sure. Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Oh, and here's some more details that my friend told me to specify:
appsrv-04.example.ca is the canonical FQDN of the host, and project.example.ca is a CNAME pointing to the A record of appsrv-04.example.ca. The known_hosts file for the git and deploy users contains all of appsrv-04, appsrv-04.example.ca,  project, and project.example.ca.

Below is the output from running cap deploy:update.

```
[user@workstation]~/Code/projectapi $ cap deploy:update
 * executing `deploy:update'
  ** transaction: start
  * executing `deploy:update_code'
updating the cached checkout on all servers
executing locally: "git ls-remote ssh://git@appsrv-04.example.ca/usr/local/git_root/projectapi.git master"
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa': 
 command finished in 4478ms
* executing "if [ -d /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q origin && git reset -q --hard e71d220f299271522517f7b4f028a9275d53326a && git clean -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q ssh://git@appsrv-04.example.ca/usr/local/git_root/projectapi.git /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/shared/cached-copy && cd /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b deploy e71d220f299271522517f7b4f028a9275d53326a; fi"
servers: ["project.example.ca"]
Enter passphrase for /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa: 
[project.example.ca] executing command
 ** [project.example.ca :: err] Permission denied, please try again.
 ** [project.example.ca :: err] Permission denied, please try again.
 ** [project.example.ca :: err] Permission denied (publickey,password).
 ** [project.example.ca :: err] fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
  command finished in 650ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
 * executing "rm -rf /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/releases/20120222225453; true"
servers: ["project.example.ca"]
[project.example.ca] executing command
command finished in 465ms
failed: "rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell '1.9.2-p290@project' -c 'if [ -d /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q origin && git reset -q --hard e71d220f299271522517f7b4f028a9275d53326a && git clean -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q ssh://git@appsrv-04.example.ca/usr/local/git_root/projectapi.git /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/shared/cached-copy && cd /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b deploy e71d220f299271522517f7b4f028a9275d53326a; fi'" on project.example.ca
```

And here's my deploy file:

```
$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path'])) 
require "rvm/capistrano"          

set :application, "Project"

set :scm, "git"
set :repository,  "ssh://git@appsrv-04.example.ca/usr/local/git_root/project.git"
set :user, "deploy"

#set :rvm_bin_path, "/usr/local/rvm/bin"
set :rvm_ruby_string, "1.9.2-p290@project"

ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

set :branch, "master"

set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

set :deploy_to, "/usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/"

set :use_sudo, false

set :domain, 'project.example.ca'

role :app, domain
role :web, domain
role :db,  domain, :primary => true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The virtual host was created by cloning an existing one and changing the IP. I updated the /etc/hosts file to use the new hostname, but apparently not the new IP. So when the deploy user was trying to ssh as the git user... it was failing because there is no git user on the IP it was using.

Answer (score 15):

You've almost certainly diagnosed this issue correctly; you're trying to check out the github repository as the deploy user and the forwarded key isn't being set up correctly. It looks like you have forward_agent turned on in Capistrano... are you adding your key to your agent so that it gets forwarded correctly?

Try doing that with `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id-rsa` and deploying again.

Comment: I set forward_agent to false and tried, and got the same result. We're not actually using an ssh-agent. We can, if it would make life easier.

My question, which user needs which keys added to which agent?

Comment: You don't want to set forward_agent to false. The problem is probably that your github repository is private so can only be accessed by certain SSH keys; the server doesn't have an allowed SSH key so it can't check out your repository. Using forward_agent allows your SSH agent to forward your private key to the server, which will use your SSH key to check out the repository from github. Set forward_agent to true and add your SSH key to the agent, and the remote server will be able to download the repository correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I've tried playing with the ssh-agent, but so far without success. Can we try the "explain-it-like-I'm-five routine"? The git repository and the deployment are happening on the same server, though in the deploy.rb they're using different hostnames. The git repo is reached via the canonical A record, while the deploy is via a CNAME record pointing at the A record. This was an arbitrary decision, and could be easily changed.

Comment: The git repo is accessed using the user "git", while the deployment is done via the user "deploy". My personal user account's key is in the authorized_keys2 file for both users, so I can log into them via ssh from my workstation.

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, when I do a cap deploy, the system logs in as the deploy user, and tries to access the git repository directly? So, the connection us deploy@project is opening an ssh connection to git@appsrv-04, which in this case just happens to be the same server but need not be.

Comment: So for this to work the deploy@project user would have to have both the appsrv-04 fingerprint in the known_hosts file, and also be able to access the git@appsrv-04 user account in some manner (ssh keys with agent-forwarding in this case), is that correct?

Comment: I actually think I completely misunderstood your problem; when you were talking about git I just assumed you were using github, but it sounds like the git repository it on the same server you're deploying to. Still, what I said earlier might still apply... Given that you're logging in with the user git, it sounds like you're using gitosis. Is that true?

Comment: Thanks for your response. We're using regular git, running git-daemon. Nothing fancy, no web access, just simple version control.

Comment: Oh, and yes, the git repository is indeed on the same server that we're deploying to.

Comment: Then I think what I proposed is actually correct. Keep your deploy file as you indicated above (with the agent forwarding turned on), and before you deploy run ```ssh-add```. Then deploy and see if that resolves the error.

Comment: Hmmm. I added my key to the ssh-agent running on my local workstation, then ran the deploy. Unfortunately, it still didn't change anything. Same error.

Comment: That is frustrating. Next step to diagnose the problem would be to actually run the offending code on the actual server itself and see if you don't get a more verbose error message -- perhaps tailing the git-daemon log while you do so would help? The command to execute is in the Capistrano log you provided, beginning with ```if [ -d /usr/local/www/...```

Comment: When I use 'su - deploy' to run as the deploy user and try to run the command, it prompts for the git user password. So the problem is clearly an issue with SSH connectivity between the user accounts. Should I be running an ssh-agent on the server itself?

Comment: And just to sanity check, when you enter in the git user password, it succeeds in cloning the repository, right?

Comment: Both the deploy and git users lack passwords. They're stared out in the /etc/shadow file. Key logins only.

Comment: I'm not totally sure where to go with this then, unfortunately... :( My earlier sureness about the root of the problem has totally evaporated. I would remove forward_agent (as it seems like you don't need it) but I'm not sure why the git user is requiring a password and returning permission denied errors. I'm sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort! Much appreciated.

Comment: The filename is usually with an underscore: `id-rsa` -> `id_rsa`